# Firebase Intent not working

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've implemented firebase push notifications in my app, the notification is working fine but when I pass intent value to Activity at notification onclick, the value is not being passed.

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService
 {
     @Override
     public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)
    {
       if(remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0)
       {
          if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null)
          {
              Log.e("Message_Notification " , remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

            Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
            Log.e("data",String.valueOf(data.size()));
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData());
            Iterator<String> iter = json.keys();
            while (iter.hasNext())
            {
               String key = iter.next();
               try
               {
                   Object value = json.get(key);
                   Log.e("key",key);
                   Log.e("value",String.valueOf(value));

                startNotification(remoteMessage,key,String.valueOf(value));
               } catch (JSONException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
public void startNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage,String key, String valueCount)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("key",key);
    intent.putExtra("value",valueCount);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    // open a notification builder
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
    notificationBuilder.setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    Log.e("body",remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(false);
    notificationBuilder.setNumber(Integer.parseInt(valueCount));
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
       /*notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);*/

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0,notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

}

And in onCreate() of MainActivity, I've used

```
   if (getIntent().hasExtra("key") && getIntent().hasExtra("value"))
    {
        String key = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
        String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("value");

          Toast.makeText(this, key, 
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

The Toast is only displaying blank

Comment: Have you tried with  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT this flag?

Comment: yes, tried with this  flag as well, but still same issue persists, can you suggest any other solutions ?